# Objective-C: Circular Protocol Requirements

Tags: objective-c

I have 2 view controllers, an object picker and an object editor. Both of these objects have their own protocols to allow the presenters to receive data & dismiss them.

The editor sometimes needs to present a picker, and the picker needs to sometimes allow objects to be edited.

The problem is that there is a circular protocol dependancy, and as the objects have to conform to the protocols, declaration forwarding doesn't work (you still get compiler warnings).

I'm not just declaring an ivar that needs to conform to it, the whole picker/editor class needs to conform, thus the headers need the full information on the protocols.

I get a `Cannot find protocol definition for 'EditorDelegate'` error.

Here's an example:

**Picker.h**

```
#import "Editor.h"
@protocol PickerDelegate;
@interface Picker : UIViewController <EditorDelegate> {
    id <PickerDelegate> delegate;
}
@protocol PickerDelegate <NSObject>
- (void)picker:(Picker *) wasDismissedWithObject:(id)object;
@end
```

**Editor.h**

```
#import "Picker.h"
@protocol EditorDelegate;
@interface Editor : UIViewController <PickerDelegate> {
    id <EditorDelegate> delegate;
}
@protocol EditorDelegate <NSObject>
- (void)editor:(Editor *) dismissedAfterEditingObject:(id)object;
@end
```

How can this be overcome?

Comment: Why are the protocol definitions in Editor.h and Picker.h and not in their own files?

Comment: Because that's a very normal way of declaring them when they're just tied to a particular object, and keeps everything neatly in the header file. However declaring them in separate files does resolve this issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can't you define the protocols in separate files, and import them in the .m files?

Comment: Yes that solved it! Hadn't thought of that, I've always declared my protocols in the header file of the related objects and never found the need to declare them in a separate file (until now!). Cheers!

Answer (score 5):

Same files solution:

```
@protocol classBProtocol;

@protocol classAProtocol <NSObject>
-(void)fooA:(id<classBProtocol>)classB;
@end

#import "classB.h"

@interface classA : NSObject
@property (nonatomic) id<classBProtocol> delegate;
@end
```

and

```
@protocol classAProtocol;

@protocol classBProtocol <NSObject>
-(void)fooB:(id<classAProtocol>)classA;
@end

#import "classA.h"

@interface classB : NSObject
@property (nonatomic) id<classAProtocol> delegate;
@end
```

The trick here is to import headers after protocol declarations.

Comment: What about a circular class (not protocol)?

Comment: Well, you can do absolutely the same thing with classes.