# Protocol declarations cannot be found - iOS

Tags: ios

When I tried having protocols in below two classes, compiler says that the protocol declarations cannot be found

ViewController:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "SecondViewController.h"

@protocol FlipOtherSideViewControllerDelegate;

@interface ViewController : UIViewController<FlipsideViewControllerDelegate>     {
    id <FlipOtherSideViewControllerDelegate> __unsafe_unretained delegate;
}

- (IBAction)switchMode:(id)sender;
@property (unsafe_unretained) id <FlipOtherSideViewControllerDelegate> delegate;

@end

 @protocol FlipOtherSideViewControllerDelegate
- (void)flipothersideViewControllerDidFinish:(ViewController *)controller;
 @end
```

SecondViewController:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "ViewController.h"

@protocol FlipsideViewControllerDelegate;

@interface SecondViewController : UIViewController   <FlipOtherSideViewControllerDelegate> {
id <FlipsideViewControllerDelegate> __unsafe_unretained delegate;
}

@property (unsafe_unretained) id <FlipsideViewControllerDelegate> delegate;
@end

@protocol FlipsideViewControllerDelegate
- (void)flipsideViewControllerDidFinish:(SecondViewController *)controller;
@end
```

Any suggestion on above?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can try do the declaration `@protocol FlipsideViewControllerDelegate
- (void)flipsideViewControllerDidFinish:(SecondViewController *)controller;
@end` instead of just `@protocol FlipsideViewControllerDelegate;`

Comment: Still the issue exists!

Comment: Ok, it seems you have recursive import problem, try use `@class ViewController;` in SeconViewController.h instead `#import "ViewController.h"` and vice versa. And import in .m files.

Comment: That did not work either. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7065558/objective-c-circular-protocol-requirements according to this, creating separate files may solve the issue. my question is that how could i have the protocol method with class parameter in the protocol?ex: - (void)flipsideViewControllerDidFinish:(SecondViewController *)controller;

Answer (score 0):

Why you declaring below the interface? Try to declare just before the interface declaration. I think there should not be any error then.

Comment: That's because i want have a protocol method having a parameter which is type of the class..